# Number of subsets the cardinality of whose intersections with some other subsets are known

Tags: combinatorics

$A$ is a non-empty finite set. $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ are subsets of $A$. How many subsets $B$'s of $A$ are there that satisfy that $|B\cap A_i|=a_i,\forall 1\leq i\leq n$, where $a_i\geq 0$'s are given integers? (Assume that we know $|A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap \ldots A_{i_k}|$, where $1\leq i_j\leq n,\forall j$.)

Thank you very much for your kindness.

Comment: Hi. What is $A_n$?

Comment: Maybe you mean the condition $|B\cap A_i|=a_i$ for each $i$, rather than what you have.

Comment: I am terribly sorry for my typo. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Paul , $A_n$ is a certain given subset of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

If the $A_i$ are disjoint, it is easy.  Let $k$ be the number of elements of $A$ that are not members of any $A_i$.  Then you need to pick $a_1$ elements out of $A_1$ and so on then any collection out of the rest, so there are $$2^k\prod_{i=1}^n {|A_i| \choose a_i}$$
If there is overlap between the $A_i$ I don't think there is an easy formula.  For example, if $A_1 \subset A_2$ and $a_2 \lt a_1$ there is no solution.